# Making elements always contain only CDATA (embedding XML examples in XML document)

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata, dtd

I'm preparing a Pressentation on XML and XSLT for my universities computing club, I'm no expert but I'm better than anyone else, and it's just a 1 hour primer.
So for my slides I figured I would use a XML document.
which I would then turn into a series of webpages with XSLT 2.0

So we have my source document

```
<slideshow>
  <slide title="Example">
    <para>Below is an example of an XML document</para>
    <code> <![CDATA[
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<elephant Name="Fido">
  <head>
    <eyes qty="2" colour="blue"/>
    <trunk/>
    <ears qty="2"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    Thin, ribs showning
  </body>
  <legs qty="4">
    Roughly 1.5m Long
  </legs>
</elephant> ]]>
    </code>
  </slide>
</slideshow>
```

Since I don't want my examples to form part of the XML structure of the document, (and don't want them to be changed by the XSLT)
I have the CDATA section.
So, everytime I have a `<code>...</code>` element, it is always written:
`<code><![CDATA[...]]></code>`
This is duplication, of information.

**Is it possible for me to declare that every `code` element only contains (Unparsed) character data?**

so i would just write  `<code>...</code>`, and it would never try to parse what was inside.

seems like something that could be done with a DTD, perhaps?

---

### The answers I'm looking for are along the lines of

Use
`<!DECLARE-CDATA-ELEMENT code>` which would make code elements, not have their content parsed .

---

You could simlate it with entitites:

```
<!ENTITY CodeStart "<code><![CDATA["> 
<!ENTITY CodeEnd "]]></code>">
```

then use: `&CodeStart;<don'tParse/>&CodeEmd;`

---

No, it can't be done, but you can Enforce that all code sections contain no child elements by ...

---

No, but you could do preproccessing like this: ...

---

These aren't answers they just indicate what answers could be like 
(hopefully this is now more clear)

Comment: No, markup outside of CDATA sections is regular markup. I didn't understand why you think having your code examples insifde CDATA is "is duplication, of information"... Could you plese, explain what is duplicated? Another possibility is to have the samples inside comments.

Comment: It is duplicated, because putting it inside a `code` element should (with the right definition for a `code` element) imply that is is CDATA. Note I'm not saying the XML should treat `code` as a special key word. I'm asking how to make it treat code as a special key word.

The duplication is that there is never a `code` tag that is not followed by a `CDATA` tag.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand a word of what you are saying. Why do you think that the W3C XML specification should be re-written in order to incorporate *your* ideas about what is correct and what not? There is only one correctness about XML -- and this is whatever is written in the W3C Specification.

Comment: If you want *not* to use any CDATA sections and still to have your samples treated as text, you must escape every `<` and `&` character in your samples to, respectively, `&lt;` and `&amp;`

Comment: Indeed, I appear to be failing to make myself clear.
I am not saying there is anything wrong with the XML spec. I'm asking a question about it because I know I don't know it fully (i know almost nothing about DTDs)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev you asked what was meant; (s)he told you and you start foaming at the mouth.  if you've got nothing useful to say, perhaps you should simply close your browser?  the question is pretty easy to understand - given that a certain element always contains CDATA, is there any way to make that implicit in the document by using a schema, dtd or similar?  if the answer is "no", you can just say so, instead of acting like the question is a personal afront to your delicate sensibilities.

Comment: @andrewcooke: If there is someone "foaming at the mouth" it definitely isn't me :) As for saying "no" -- you need to read better -- I already said it. :)

Comment: Comments are not answers. If "no" is your answer, then post it, so I can accept it, if there is no better answers.

Comment: @Oxinabox: If I were in your place I would be suspicious towards answers that appear "in no time". Some definite time is necessary for a *good* and accurate answer. Now you have mine.

Comment: I never stated otherwise. I rather dislike it, when the best answers appear as comments, and was worried yours might stay that way.

Comment: @Oxinabox: I didn't stay that way. Is the answer satisfactory to you?

Comment: it's a good answer  (i'll wait a few days before i accept anything)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since I don't want my examples to form part of the XML structure of
>   the document, (and don't want them to be changed by the XSLT) I have
>   the CDATA section.

**It isn't necessary to use CDATA section in order to protect some XML fragment from being "changed by the XSLT" -- simply write your XSLT code in such a way that it copies any subtree rooted at a `code` element**.

> Is it possible forme to declare that every code element only contains
>   (Unparsed) character data?

**Yes, but XSLT doesn't require that there be a DTD for either the source XML document or for the result of the processing** (Schema-aware XSLT 2.0 can validate these and even intermediate results, but it works only with XML Schema (XSD) ), and in case there is such DTD, XSLT doesn't use any type information (with the only exception being the fact that there is an ID attribute). Therefore, providing such a DTD isn't going to be helpful.

**Also, such a DTD will be violated, unless you escape at least every `&` and `<` character** in the child text-node of `code`:

**From the [W3C XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#syntax)**:

> *"[Definition: All text that is not markup constitutes the character data of the document.]  The ampersand character (&) and the left angle
>   bracket (<) MUST NOT appear in their literal form, except when used as
>   markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a
>   CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped
>   using either numeric character references or the strings " & " and
>   " < " respectively*."

Comment: With your first solution I run into a problem if my Xml fragement contains a `<?xml version="1.0"?>` header though, right? other than thatit works quiet well.
That was what I was considering initially. Along with perhaps putting them in a different namespace? (to get around the other problem of names being picked up by the XSLT)

Comment: @Oxinabox: This isn't a "header" -- this is *XML declaration*. It isn't necessary (because `version="1.0"` is the default), so simply don't include any XML declarations.

Answer (score 2):

I see your point about the relation of `code` and CDATA sections:  if you never have one without the other, then one of them is not carrying much information.  But no, the other answers are quite correct:  there is no way to declare that `code` elements should be parsed differently.

For what it's worth, SGML DTDs do have the capability to declare elements using the `CDATA` keyword, with the meaning "everything inside this element is character data, not markup, so don't recognize delimiters here".  Of course, you do want to recognize the end of the element, so things get fairly complicated fairly quickly, and the `CDATA` declaration turned out (even after all the complications) not to do a great job for the use case you describe.

So we might have deep-sixed `CDATA` element declarations in XML even if we hadn't had the motivation mentioned by Andrew Cooke:  any facility for allowing declarations to change parser behavior makes it impossible to parse without reading the DTD.

So:  the redundancy you object to is essentially a consequence of the fact that you are addressing two different audiences:  the `CDATA` marked section talks to the parser about what to parse and how, and the `code` element talks to the downstream app (e.g. your XSLT stylesheet) about the logical structure of the document.  A small example of the general principle that careful layering of simple processes sometimes increases verbosity.

I hope your presentation went well.

Answer (score 1):

first, i know of no mechanism that would do this.

second, by my limited understanding of the xml standard, i don't think what you want could exist.  the xml specification has a concept of "well-formed" that applies to xml documents without (or "before" if you like) a DTD, and your document without the CDATA would not be well-formed.

in other words, xml documents have to follow certain rules by themselves; what you are asking for is that these rules be relaxed/changed by a DTD, but DTD only provides further checks in addition to well-formedness (leading to "valid" documents), they can't change the well-formed requirements.

but i am no great xml expert...

ps the problem is see is with the `<?xml... ?>` part; as another answer says, you can embed the xml elements inside your document directly (in that case, if you want to make the difference between the "containing" and "embedded" xml more explicit look at xml namespaces).

Comment: Thanks, I was hopeful that perhaps DTD, would have a solution. Since they do allow the creation of Entities, (which is not strictly part of the Validating goal)

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined not to embed the example documents, but to reference them:

```
<code ref="example1.xml"/>
```

Comment: for longer ones perhaps, but most of mine are less than 4 lines long. (Some being just "this is a start tag `<ele>`)